# Searching for multiple cases in a string using regex in Python 2.7x

Tags: regex, python-2.7

So I get some data from a csv, I want to normalise all the rows on the nr_nou column so they have just "FARA NUMAR" in that cell, instead of "f n", "fn ", "Fara numar" etc... 
I'm going to give out the chunks of code that are relevant:

```
pattern1 = re.compile(r"\b\s*f\s*a*r*a*\s*nu*m*a*r*\s*\b")

elif ind == nr_nou:
                    if re.search(pattern1, data):
                        data = "FARA NUMAR"
```

Part of a CSV row:

```
device2,120L,13/07/2019 12:51,Sat Daia,F.N.,Fara Numar,14,,,INCOMPLETA,,,45.8007164,24.2572791,"45.8007164,24.2572791"
```

So next I would like to change those two values "F.N." and "Fara Numar"
Regards!

Comment: Please show some sample data from the CSV file, and also include what it should look like after the replacement.

Comment: hey, thanks for your prompt reply. Just added a bit of CSV, can't give much as it's some confidential data. Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so a friend gave me the answer. It has to be case insensitive, like this:

```
pattern1 = re.compile(r'\b\s*f\s*a*r*a*\s*nu*m*a*r*\s*\b', re.IGNORECASE)

elif ind == nr_nou:
                    if re.search(pattern1, data):
                        data = "FARA NUMAR"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `re.sub` with an appropriate pattern:

```
row = "device2,120L,13/07/2019 12:51,Sat Daia,F.N.,Fara Numar,14,,,INCOMPLETA,,,45.8007164,24.2572791,45.8007164,24.2572791"
row = re.sub(r'(?<![^,])(?:F\.N\.|Fara Numar)(?![^,])', 'FARA NUMAR', text)
print(row)
```

This prints:

```
device2,120L,13/07/2019 12:51,Sat Daia,FARA NUMAR,FARA NUMAR,14,,,INCOMPLETA,,,45.8007164,24.2572791,45.8007164,24.2572791
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```
(?<![^,])       assert that what precedes is either comma of the start of the input
(?:
    F\.N\.       match "F.N."
    |            OR
    Fara Numar   match "Fara Numar"
)
(?![^,])         assert that what follows is either comma or the end of the input
```

Comment: While it is an option, it is not the best. I have some users that keep pushing in many formats of this string... I need something that is close to both "fn" and to "fara numar"- this means No Number.